# What is range of values that the word 'nearby' supposed to represent in this informal definition of continuity.

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

In my book it gave two informal explanation for the concept of continuity. I had doubt in the second explanation but I cleared it by asking it here. The explanation is ,

> Suppose a function f has the value f(p) at a certain point p. Then f is said to be continuous at p if at every nearby point x the function value f(x) is close to f(p).

My doubt is that what is range of values that the word 'nearby' supposed to represent because if we keep p=3 both 2 and 4 are near to 3 , 2.5 and 3.5 is also near to 3 and many more numbers are near to 3 I just want to know how near is nearby?

The book name is 'Calculus', Author is Tom Apostol.

Comment: With all respect to Apostol, the phrasing "We can make $f(x)$ as close as we like to $f(p)$ by taking $x$ sufficiently close to $p$" more literally translates the formal definition into conceptual prose.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to know how near is nearby?

It's *as near as it needs to be*. It should be seen as kind of a challenge. If you prescribe a distance $\varepsilon$ around $f(p)$, there is as distance $\delta$ around $p$ such that if $x$ is at less than $\delta$ from $p$, then $f(x)$ is at less than $\varepsilon$ from $f(p)$.

Actual value for $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$, on $p$, and on $f$.